# How to register a column handler windows 10

Tags: windows, registry, explorer, shell-extensions

I am trying to add a custom column to windows 10 explorer. The onedrive application also implements this with the status column:
[image: Onedrive]

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3747/Explorer-column-handler-shell-extension-in-C

According to this website I need to simply add a columnhandler in the registry. So I've looked in my registry and found the subkey where I need to register the handler.

[image: registry]

I know how to use the IColumnHandler interface on an object. But how can I refer in the registry to this object? And do I need to compile this object to a dll file or some other sort of file?

Any help would be greatly  appreciated

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlobj/nn-shlobj-icolumnprovider "Support for IColumnProvider has been removed as of Windows Vista. The Windows property system is used in its place. See Windows Property System for conceptual materials that explain the use of the new system."